# Do we need to divide components and containers in separate folders in React / Redux projects?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Short question: should we put components and containers into separate folders or should we just put them all in the `components` folder?

---

Details: I think the standard is, if it is a component that is not tied to the Redux state (the app state), then it is just a component and would go into the `components` folder.

And if it is a component that is tied up to the Redux state, then it is called a container and should go into the `containers` folder.

But I also see some project that doesn't distinguish them and just put everything into the `components` folder.

Is there a standard as to whether we should divide them or just put them all together?

Comment: In my kitchen - should I store pepper and salt separately or in a set? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52Vt8Fg3ZPY

Answer (score 2):

There are actually 2 ways to organise your application's code:

## First

> actions/
>
> > CommandActions.js
> >
> > UserActions.js
>
> components/
>
> > Header.js
> >
> > Sidebar.js
>
> containers/
>
> > App.js
>
> reducers/
>
> > index.js
> >
> > bar.js

## Second

> product/
>
> > Product.js
> >
> > ProductContainer.js
> >
> > ProductActions.js
> >
> > ProductList.js
> >
> > ProductItem.js
> >
> > ProductImage.js
> >
> > productReducer.js
>
> user/
>
> > User.js
> >
> > UserContainer.js
> >
> > UserActions.js
> >
> > UserProfile.js
> >
> > UserAvatar.js
> >
> > userReducer.js

The second structure should be used in case your project is complex and contains a lot of modules.

Answer (score 1):

You should put them in separate folders -- I think it's more clear if you understand the distinction between what a `container` is and what a `component` is. Here is a [good article](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005) but to rip out the most important distinction:

> A container does data fetching and then renders its corresponding sub-component. That’s it.

In general, the main benefit of distinguishing components from containers is you separate the UI from the data fetching. The UI could potentially be used in different places in your app with different data and this allows you to do that.

If you shove all of them in the same folder, that's fine but how do you know which of your components are UI and reusable and which are for data fetching? Sure you could just call all of the ones that are containers and suffix them with `Container` but that shouldn't be a requisite. It's preferred you simply do that only if you have a UI component that goes with it.

This is also a good Github issue talking about [containers vs components](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/756) where they also talk about some other benefits in separating them out (routing, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Generally the standard in react apps whether redux is used or not, to put 'pages' like 'Home', 'User', 'Settings' etc. in containers folder and to put common ui elements like 'button', 'header', 'sidebar' in components folder.

If you're making, let's say a 'user-avatar' component in 'user' page than make a folder named 'user' under containers and put 'user-avatar' there.

However when we include redux into discussion, there is an interesting proposal called 'redux-ducks' which you should check out.

Comment: the rule I heard was whether the component is tied to the app state... if tied, then call it a container and put it in the `containers` folder... and it looks similar to what you described: user, which is app state, is container, and button is not tied to any app state, and therefore is just components and go in the components folder.  So then, it looks like we should use 2 separate folders

Comment: There isn't actually any rule.It is totally upto you.Whichever way looks more organised to use go with it.